Angular mat-table same data shows in all input fields after clicking add rows in mat table?
I am implementing dynamic rows based on user entered number in input field in my case rows added based on the input value but after edit any single row its value reflect in the different rows. I have already tried with name attribute on a input field but same issue can anybody check below code and let me know what's wrong:
addRow(rowsCount: string) {
   const rowsCountValue = Number(rowsCount);
   let newItemObject: any = {};
   //
   for (let i = 0; i < rowsCountValue; i++) {
      this.visibleColumns.forEach(column => {
         this.defaultValueColumnList.includes(column) ?
            newItemObject[column] = this.commonEmitterService.loggedInUserInfo?.displayName :
            newItemObject[column] = '';
      });
      newItemObject.isEdit = true;
      newItemObject.id = this.dataSource.data.length + 1;
      this.dataSource.data.unshift(newItemObject);
      //this.dataSource.data.unshift(Object.assign(newItemObject, { isEdit: true,id:currentItemIndex++ }));
   }
   this.dataSource.data = [...this.dataSource.data]
}

HTML:
<! Input field for add rows–>
<input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter no of row"  #currentValue>
<div class="input-group-prepend" (click)="addRow(currentValue.value)">Add rows
</div>
 <! table for data–>

<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
   <ng-container [matColumnDef]="col.property" *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
      {{ col.label }}
   </th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <mat-form-field [appearance]="fieldAppearance">
         <input matInput [required]="col.required" type="text" [(ngModel)]="element[col.property]"
         required/>
      </mat-form-field>
   </td>
   </ng-container>
</table>

